# Date/Time range picker for angular material

Tags: angularjs, datepicker, angular-material, daterangepicker, angular-daterangepicker

I am using angular material for my project.

I need date range picker for some functionalities & date-time range picker for some functionalities.

I have searched for it but i am not able to find any picker with all working functionality.

I have tried smDateTimeRangePicker but it didn't work with start-date. always open picker with current date. it also doesn't have functionality of dynamic min/max date.

Can anyone point me on right direction where i can fine range picker with working start, min, max,.. functionalities.

Comment: seems like answer doesn't match with material date picker .. can it be possible with https://material.angular.io/components/datepicker/examples ?

Answer (score 0):

The best angular js date time picker is 
We can choose 720kb datepicker for date alone, it has nice UI and nice features.
[720kb datepicker](https://github.com/720kb/angular-datepicker)

```
<datepicker date-format="MM/dd/yyyy">
   <input type="text" maxlength="10" id="dtdate"
       ng-model="model.date" placeholder="mm/dd/yyyy">
</datepicker>
```

The best time picker is angular moment picker
[angular moment picker for time](https://github.com/indrimuska/angular-moment-picker)

```
<input show-header="false" moment-picker="@NGModel2" format="HH:mm" 
today="true" min-view="day" ng-model="model.time" maxlength="5 " 
id="time"  placeholder="HH:mm" />
```

The screenshot for both date picker and time picker below
[image: date time picker snapshot]